# Ajax response error

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I need to make a mysql query according to the value of dropdown list. Here I use ajax to send dropdown value to the server. I think this part is working for me. But problem is I can not get it to php. Note: both are in the same page.

This is my Jquery code :

```
$('#filter-value').change(function(){
    var filterValue = $(this).val();
    //console.log(filterValue); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {filter: filterValue},
        success:function(data){ 
            alert(data); 
        }, 
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            //On error, we alert user
            alert(thrownError);
        }, 
        complete: function(){
            //alert('update success'); 
        }
    });
});
```

This is HTML form

```
    <form method="post" action="">
        <select id="filter-value" name="filter">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>              
        </select>
    </form>
```

This is my PHP code  that I am trying on the top of the page :

```
if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    $filter = $_POST['filter']; 
    echo $filter; 
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'bad';
}
```

But this php code is always going to else part and print 'bad'

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Add `echo json_encode($_POST)` to the else clause.

Comment: Your code checks out. Tell me what do you get if you do `var_dump($_POST); exit;` on the top of the PHP

Comment: @Starx I tried it and display this `array(0) { } ` on the page

Comment: @Barmar it print this `bad[]`

Comment: @TNK, It is not the value Dude, specify the url now even if it the same page.

Comment: @Starx I tried adding url and var_dump($_POST) on the top of the web

Comment: @Starx Then I got this `array(1) {
  ["filter"]=>
  string(2) "30"
} from the alert box that I have added to success function.

Comment: @TNK, It is working after specify the URL, now remove the `var_dump` and your code will work as usual.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32605/discussion-between-tnk-and-starx)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to specify the URL of the script. Be ensure that you are querying the correct file from the AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'yourpage.php', // This one 
    //.....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your php to (and say save as xyz.php):

```
if($_POST) {
if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
    $filter = $_POST['filter']; 
    echo $filter; 
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'bad';
}
}
```

and url to your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "xyz.php",
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {filter: filterValue},
    success:function(data){ 
        alert(data); 
    },
```

Comment: you need to post to the file with this php script through your ajax call

Comment: RAJ please tell me what do you mean in above comment

Comment: Answer edited. Note that the url you post to in the ajax call hits your php script

Comment: do I need to add php to new page?

Comment: not necessarily. you can post to the same page. however, you need to make sure you have the url parameter accordingly in your ajax